# Python GUI generate math equation

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a homework question for one specific item with python GUIs.

My goal is to create a GUI that asks a random mathematical equation and if the equation is evaluated correctly, then I will receive a message stating that it is correct.

My main problem is finding out where to place my statements so that they show up in the labels; I have 1 textbox which generates the random equation, the next textbox is blank for me to enter the solution, and then an "Enter" button at the end to evaluate my solution.

It looks like this:

```
[*randomly generated equation*][*Empty space to enter solution*] [ENTER]
```

I've managed to get the layout and the evaluate parameters, but I don't know where to go from here.

This is my code so far:

```
class Equation(Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        Equation.make_widgets(self)
        Equation.new_problem(self)

    def make_widgets(self):
        Label(self).grid(row=0, column=1)
        ent = Entry(self)
        ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Label(self).grid(row=0, column=2)
        ent = Entry(self)
        ent.grid(row=0, column=2)
        Button(self, text='Enter', command=self.evaluate).grid(row=0, column=3)

    def new_problem(self):
        pass

    def evaluate(self):
        result = eval(self.get())
        self.delete(0, END)
        self.insert(END, result)
        print('Correct')
```

Comment: This question, as it stands now, falls under the category "too localized". To prevent your question from being closed, I would consider rephrasing your question so that the answer will be more helpful to other users of this site. An example of this would be, "How do I change the value of a Tkinter Label from inside of a callback function?". (A callback is the function that gets called when an event is raised, in this case, `self.evaluate` is the relevant callback function.-- I assume that this is what you're really trying to do.)

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I've recently begun with GUIs so I don't really know how to group GUI functions into a proper question.

Comment: use `self.make_widgets()` instead of `Equation.make_widgets(self)`

Answer (score 1):

```
self.labeltext = StringVar() # in __init__

# ...
Label(self, textvariable=self.labeltext) # in make_widgets

# ...
self.labeltext.set("Correct!") # in evaluate
```

Answer (score 0):

In `make_widgets()`, you're creating a bunch of widgets, but not assigning them to any variables. This prevents you from being able to access them after you create them. Try assigning them to instance variables, e.g.:

```
def make_widgets(self):
        self.equation_label = Label(self)
        self.equation_label.grid(row=0, column=1) #notice that grid() is on another line
        self.entry1 = Entry(self)
        ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.solution_label = Label(self)
        self.solution_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self)
        ent.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.button = Button(self, text='Enter', command=self.evaluate)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=3)
```

That way, you could access them from other functions within the class like so:

```
self.solution_label.config(text="Hello World")
```

So your callback would end up looking more like this:

```
def evaluate(self):
        result = eval(self.get())
        self.solution_label.config(text=str(result))
```

For the `Entry` widget, you can either use J.F.Sebastian's answer, or you can use the `insert`  and `delete` methods (which it appears you were trying to do anyway):

```
def evaluate(self):
    #...some code...
    self.solution_entry.delete(0, END)
    self.solution_entry.insert(0, "Some text")
    #...more code...
```

[Tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) is a excellent resource for looking up widget configuration options and the like.

*EDIT*

See [J.F.Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12877426/1142167) for another way to set widget values.

Comment: I'm making some syntax progress, but I have a small question about self.get(). Is 'get' specifically tied to the Tk import? As of now I'm receiving errors about get not being defined, yet in my notes, self.get works fine with just a single input. Also, since the code I've posted came from the homework template, Tk was not imported.

Comment: `self` in this case presumably refers to an instance of `Frame`. `Frame` doesn't have a `get()` method. What you do in `make_widgets` is create, say, a `StringVar` object, and set it equal to `self.some_var_name`. `StringVar` *does* have a `get()` method. You would access it like so: `self.some_var_name.get()`.

Comment: @NeroDietrich Also, I caught something else in your `make_widgets()` method. See how I placed the `grid()` method on a separate line above.

Comment: Ah, J.F. Sebastian's input makes sense now. Thank you.